# Installing dotnet-sdk-3.1 has no effect

Tags: .net, .net-core, installation, dotnet-sdk

On Ubuntu 18.04 I am attempting to update from dotnet 3.0 to 3.1. I have been thru the process described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-manager-ubuntu-1804) several times but it simply doesn't appear to work. I get the following result:

```
dave@NUC3:~$ sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-3.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dotnet-sdk-3.1 is already the newest version (3.1.201-1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.

dave@NUC3:~$ dotnet --list-sdks
3.0.100-preview6-012264 [/home/dave/dotnet/sdk]
3.0.100-rc1-014190 [/home/dave/dotnet/sdk]
dave@NUC3:~$
```

Version 3.1 simply never shows up in the list of SDKs.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try uninstall `3.0.100-preview6-012264` and `3.0.100-rc1-014190`, and then reinstall 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OS is corrupt. I was unable to add or remove packages without errors. So I created a new VM and started from scratch.